# Kotlin for a Cordova/Ionic based plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, kotlin, ionic3

is it possible to use Kotlin as a framework/language as a Cordova plugin?

first issue is that it's not copying the .kt file, because it looks for *.java or *.xml

if so anyone know a reference on how to setup?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recently I've been working with Kotlin in Cordova plugins, but when I started out I also couldn't find any existing references as to how to create a Cordova plugin using Kotlin.

So I've created an example plugin which you can use as a template:
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin

As you can see, the native part on the Cordova plugin interface is [implemented in Kotlin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin/blob/master/src/HelloKotlin.kt).

Because currently `cordova-android@7` doesn't implicitly support Kotlin, the plugin uses hook scripts to set up the native Android project created by Cordova for Kotlin, and also to remove `.kt` files from the platform project when the plugin is uninstalled, since currently `cordova-android@7` only does this for `.java` files.

But it works and you can try it out with the [test app project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin).

Comment: Thanks Dave, it's help my day, since kotlin is very magic language i very curious to implement kotlin in my old plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Official solution: [cordova 9 supports kotlin](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/29/cordova-android-9.0.0.html)

add the following in config.xml

```
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinCodeStyle" value="official" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinVersion" value="1.3.50" />
```

also note where to put the kotlin files, i.e. `src/main/kotlin/<com>/<package>/`

using:

```
<source-file src="src/android/file.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/kotlin/xx/yy/zz" />
```

and add the below to your plugin's gradle.build if the kotlin files aren't picked up by your project

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.java {
            srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    }
}
```

[This plugin uses kotlin and has an example project](https://github.com/timbru31/cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen/tree/master/example)

Comment: I'm getting `Failed to install 'cordova-***': Error: Variable(s) missing: GRADLEPLUGINKOTLINENABLED, GRADLEPLUGINKOTLINCODESTYLE, GRADLEPLUGINKOTLINVERSION`

Comment: I also got that error when putting it in plugin.xml. It works fine in config.xml.

Comment: Inside the plugin.xml within the <platform name="android">.. you should have something like <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">.. you should put these <preference.. for kotlin  (from the docs) inside there..

Comment: The linked plugin does not include any .kt source files, maybe a better example could be provided.