# How to add Android Kotlin files to a Cordova Plugin project

Tags: java, kotlin, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to add Android Kotlin files to a **Cordova Plugin** project or is only Java supported?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        version="0.0.1">

  <!-- android -->
  <platform name="android">

    <source-file src="src/android/nl/companyname/kotlin/ScanMode.kt" target-dir="src/nl/companyname/kotlin"/>

  </platform>

</plugin>
```

The Java files show up, but the Kotlin files don't.
I also don't see any [plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?platforms=cordova-android) that has it.

Comment: i think this link may be useful for you  https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add the following in config.xml

```xml
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinEnabled" value="true" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinCodeStyle" value="official" />
<preference name="GradlePluginKotlinVersion" value="1.3.50" />
```

also note where to put the kotlin files, i.e. src/main/kotlin///

using:

```
<source-file src="src/android/file.kt" target-dir="app/src/main/kotlin/xx/yy/zz" />
```

and add the below to your plugin's gradle.build if the kotlin files aren't picked up by your project

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.java {
            srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        }
    }
}
```

This answer is referenced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63872580/10999673

I modifed an example repository to test this:

https://github.com/kilisio/cordova-plugin-hello-kotlin.git

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin support was added in [Cordova 9.0.0](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md#900-jun-23-2020), which was released on January 23 2020. Here you can find more information:
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/29/cordova-android-9.0.0.html

Comment: yeah but the question was specific about Cordova Plugin.